# How to add entity data model programmatically in runtime to Web Api project?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, web-config, connection-string

Is it possible to add entity framework in runtime to Web Api Project?

For example/scenario;

The company will add to one Branch in runtime. The branch's database informations such as 
-connection string
-database name 
are stored in a table of the company's database.

How can I add the branch's database connectionstring in Web.config fie? and How to connect to the database?

Answer (score 0):

you can initialize DbContext with connection string

```
public MyContext(): DbContext
{
    Public MyContext(){};
    Public MyContext(string connectionString):base(connection){};
}
```

and initilize like below :

```
var firstBranch = new MyContext("firstBranchConnection");
var secondBranch = new MyContext("secondBranchConnection");
```